# Adding moment locale break the initial date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs, locale

I have a weird issue with moment that i cannot explain:

I have my date : `Wed Feb 28 2018 16:24:37 GMT+0100 (CET)`

When I add `import 'moment/locale/fr';` the same date becomes `Sun Jan 28 2018 16:24:37 GMT+0100 (CET)`

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong ?

here is the complete example

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
// ====== adding locale break the date    ======= //
// import 'moment/locale/fr';

// time value is : Wed Feb 28 2018 16:24:37 GMT+0100 (CET)

const Time = ({ time }) => (
    <p>
        {moment(time).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss')}
    </p>
);

// output without locale/fr is : 28-02-2018 16:24:37
// output with locale/fr is : 28-01-2018 16:24:37
```

After that I will use `.fromNow()`moment function to display the time distance between now and the given time.

Comment: Show the code in the question, see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RobG I've updated the code.
It's a simple stateless react component that display the date

Comment: What is the value of `time`? Anyway use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) or [`toString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-string/) to print the value of a moment object.

Comment: @VincenzoC I have updated the code with the input and the output with and without adding locale/fr

Comment: why do you need to use `moment/locale/fr` if your time value is in English and your `format()` doesn't have any locale-specific output?

Comment: @AlexK because I wanna use .fromNow() moment function to display the distance between now and the date.

It is the time displayed on a chat component i am developing.

the real output will be "one minute ago" but I need to handle languages (english, french...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you parse a string without providing the input format, moment.js first tries ISO 8601 format. If it doesn't match, it falls back to the built-in parser. You should be getting a warning not to do that (because it's a bad idea).

If you provide the parse format ('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ') with a locale file of French and don't specify that the input string is English, then the string seems to be parsed as if it was French and "Feb" is parsed as "janvier" (January) rather than février (February).

You need to provide the parse format and language of the input string:

```
moment('Wed Feb 28 2018 16:24:37 GMT+0100 (CET)', 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ', 'en')
```

```js
// Without providing parse format
console.log(moment('Wed Feb 28 2018 16:24:37 GMT+0100 (CET)').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'));

// With parse format but not input langauge
console.log(moment('Wed Feb 28 2018 16:24:37 GMT+0100 (CET)', 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'));

// With parse format and input langauge (recommended approach)
console.log(moment('Wed Feb 28 2018 16:24:37 GMT+0100 (CET)', 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ', 'en').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/locale/fr.js"></script>
```

Comment: first format parameter should be `ddd` not `do`, `do` is `1st..31st - Day of month with ordinal`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (we need import from `moment/locale/fr` to make sure it loads on client side). So parse in English, then switch locale to the one you need, and then output the time difference with `fromNow`:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import momentFr from 'moment/locale/fr';

const Time = ({ time }) => (
    <p>
        {moment(time, 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss Z').locale('fr').fromNow()}
    </p>
);
```

Comment: It shoud display `one day ago` but instead The output is wrong `il y a un mois` equivalent of `one month ago`

Comment: even by giving the exact format it's not working (it even displays sometimes "invalid date"

Comment: @Ayyoub so your `time` is in different format that you show us, I used exactly your string from post `Wed Feb 28 2018 16:24:37 GMT+0100 (CET)`

Comment: Does it work ?
I hard coded the date and it didn't work :(